# Raspberry Pi 4 yocto, rpi-basic-image.bb: Unable to determine endianness for architecture 'INVALID'

Tags: yocto, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to build core-image-minimal for raspberrypi4-64 on the zeus branch
and I had to create the file sanity.conf and I'm getting this errors:

```
fstrati$ bitbake -c cleanall core-image-minimal
Loading cache: 100% Time: 0:00:00
Loaded 28 entries from dependency cache.
ERROR: rpi-basic-image.bb: Unable to determine endianness for architecture 'INVALID'
ERROR: rpi-basic-image.bb: Please add your architecture to siteinfo.bbclass
ERROR: rpi-hwup-image.bb: Unable to determine endianness for architecture 'INVALID'
ERROR: rpi-hwup-image.bb: Please add your architecture to siteinfo.bbclass
ERROR: Failed to parse recipe: rpi-hwup-image.bb
ERROR: vte_0.56.3.bb: Unable to determine endianness for architecture 'INVALID'
ERROR: vte_0.56.3.bb: Please add your architecture to siteinfo.bbclass
```

I don't understand why core-image-minimal is using such deprecated recipes.

do I need to switch to the master branch?

Forgive me if this is a dumb question...

Comment: There's no dumb question. What did you set for you MACHINE variable ?

Comment: BB_NUMBER_THREADS = "2"
# Also, make can be passed flags so it run parallel threads e.g.:
PARALLEL_MAKE = "-j 2"
MACHINE ?= "raspberrypi4-64.conf"

Comment: `fstrati@fstrati-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx:/media/fstrati/Bkp20191226/yocto_try/poky$ inxi 
CPU~Dual core AMD A9-9425 RADEON R5 5 COMPUTE CORES 2C+3G (-MCP-) speed/max~1937/3100 MHz Kernel~5.0.0-37-generic x86_64 Up~16:26 Mem~4276.3/7500.6MB HDD~1500.3GB(7.6% used) Procs~323 Client~Shell inxi~2.3.56  
`

Comment: `System:    Host: fstrati-HP-Laptop-15-db0xxx Kernel: 5.0.0-37-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: HP product: HP Laptop 15-db0xxx v: Type1ProductConfigId serial: N/A
           Mobo: HP model: 84AC v: 85.20 serial: N/A UEFI: Insyde v: F.11 date: 08/20/2018`

Comment: It seems my MACHINE configuration was wrong.

I tried with MACHINE ?= "raspberrypi4-64" instead and everything went fine.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems my MACHINE configuration was wrong. I tried with MACHINE ?= "raspberrypi4-64" instead and everything went fine.

Removing conf resolved issue for me as well.